# Swiper slider dynamic pagination

Tags: javascript, css, frontend, swiper.js

I'm using swiper slider and don't know how to get rid of the empty space when the slider comes to the first or last element, can you tell me please
https://monosnap.com/file/jLTCNd8CIT82h6WNqGbP5qxVKWkS8d

Tried find some property in Swiper slider API and make styles

{
"loop": true,
"slidesPerView": 3,
"observer": true,
"loopFillGroupWithBlank": true,
"slidesPerGroup": 1,
"initialSlide": 3,
"navigation": {
"nextEl": ".collection-slider-2-swiper-button-next",
"prevEl": ".collection-slider-2-swiper-button-prev"
},
"pagination": {
"el": ".swiper-pagination",
"dynamicBullets": true
},
"breakpoints": {
"320": {
"slidesPerView": 2,
"spaceBetween": 20,
"pagination": {
"type": "progressbar"
}
},
"1024": {
"slidesPerView": 2,
"pagination": {
"type": "bullets"
}
},
"1440": {
"slidesPerView": 3,
"spaceBetween": 30
}
}
}

Comment: Can you please add a [minimal reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.